# TypeError: product.product(3,) is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, odoo

I'm having so much issues with this code now. Here is my function :

```py
def _get_invoice_lines(self):
    self.cr.execute("SELECT inv.number,l.price_subtotal_taxed,l.name,inv.maitre_ouvrage,m.type_paiement,m.ref,m.date 
        FROM product_product p,account_invoice inv, account_invoice_line l,account_move ml
        where p.id = l.product_id
        and inv.id= l.invoice_id
        and ml.invoice_id=inv.id
        and ml.type_paiement is not null
        and inv.journal_id = 1
        and ml.type_paiement = '%s'
        and  inv.date_invoice =DATE '%s'
        and  p.id = %d "%(self.datas['type_paiement'],self.datas['date_invoice'],self.datas['product_id'].id))
    return self.cr.fetchall()
```

When I print my report I get this error :

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 239, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: product.product(3,) is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you l.product_id is completely product object and you just need the id.

Did you test **l.product_id.id**?

Probably you going to get the same error with inv.id= l.invoice_id. Same solution!